# How to prove the arithmetic equality `3 * S (i + j) + 1 = S (3 * i + 1) + S (3 * j + 1)` in Coq?

Tags: coq

How to prove the equality

```
3 * S (i + j) + 1 = S (3 * i + 1) + S (3 * j + 1)`
```

in Coq?

Trying to prove my induction hypothesis in Coq, I need to prove that these sides are equal (which they obviously are).

However, if I remove `S` on ,e.g., the left-hand side, then I get the natural number `3`. But, I don't know how to decompose this into `1 + 1 + 1`.

Also, sitting and fidling with `Nat.add_assoc` and `Nat.add_comm` is very time consuming and makes me crazy.

There must be some "straightforward" way for a beginner how to prove this using "basic" tactics?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's do some automatic proofs first. To compare them with the (much) longer manual proof I came up with.

```
Require Import
Arith      (* `ring` tactic on `nat` and lemmas *)
Omega      (* `omega` tactic *)
Psatz.     (* `lia`, `nia` tactics *)

Goal forall i j,
    3 * S (i + j) + 1 = S (3 * i + 1) + S (3 * j + 1).
Proof.
```

### The `ring` tactic

The Coq Reference Manual, [§8.16.3:](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#sec436)

> The `ring` tactic solves equations upon polynomial expressions of a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)) (or [semi-ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring)) structure. It proceeds by normalizing both hand sides of the equation (w.r.t. associativity, commutativity and distributivity, constant propagation) and comparing syntactically the results.

```
  intros; ring.
  Undo.
```

### The `omega` tactic

The Coq Reference Manual, [§8.16.2:](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#sec435)

> The tactic `omega`, due to Pierre Crégut, is an automatic decision procedure for [Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic). It solves quantifier-free formulas built with `~`, `\/`, `/\`, `->` on top of equalities, inequalities and disequalities on both the type `nat` of natural numbers and `Z` of binary integers. This tactic must be loaded by the command `Require Import Omega`. See the additional documentation about `omega` (see Chapter 21).

```
  intros; omega.
  Undo.
```

### The `lia` tactic

The Coq Reference Manual, [§22.5:](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual025.html#sec710)

> The tactic `lia` offers an alternative to the `omega` and `romega` tactic (see Chapter 21). Roughly speaking, the deductive power of `lia` is the combined deductive power of `ring_simplify` and `omega`. However, it solves linear goals that `omega` and `romega` do not solve, such as the following so-called omega nightmare [130].

```
  intros; lia.
  Undo.
```

### The `nia` tactic

The Coq Reference Manual, [§22.6:](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual025.html#sec714)

> The `nia` tactic is an experimental proof procedure for non-linear integer arithmetic. The tactic performs a limited amount of non-linear reasoning before running the linear prover of `lia`...

```
  intros; nia.
  Undo.
```

### A manual proof

All the above tactics automatically solve the goal. `Undo` is a Vernacular command that "un-does" a step, it allows us to restart the proof from the beginning, the same effect in this case could've been achieved using the `Restart` command.

Now, let's do a manual proof. I didn't delete the `Search` commands I used to find the necessary lemmas for didactic reasons. Frankly, I don't use them too often and do not remember their names -- it much easier to use the automatic tactics.

One of the main difficulties (at least for me) is to "focus" on the subexpression of the goal I want to make a rewrite in.
For that purpose we can use the `replace ... with ...` tactic (see an example below) and `symmetry` (to some extent). `symmetry` turns a goal of the form `a = b` into `b = a` -- it allows you to rewrite in `b` rather than in `a`.

Also, `rewrite !<lemma>` helps a lot too -- the exclamation point means "do rewrites as many times as possible".

```
  intros.
  Search (S (?n + ?m) = ?n + S ?m).
  rewrite !plus_n_Sm.
  rewrite <- Nat.add_assoc.
  Search (?n + (?m + ?p) = ?m + (?n + ?p)).
  rewrite Nat.add_shuffle3.
  symmetry.
  rewrite Nat.add_comm.
  rewrite Nat.add_assoc.
  Search (?k * ?x + ?k * ?y).
  rewrite <- Nat.mul_add_distr_l.
  replace (S j) with (j + 1) by now rewrite Nat.add_comm.
  rewrite Nat.add_assoc.
  symmetry.
  rewrite Nat.mul_add_distr_l.
  rewrite <- !Nat.add_assoc.
  reflexivity.
Qed.
```

The above manual proof can be compressed into this equivalent form:

```
  intros.
  rewrite !plus_n_Sm, <- Nat.add_assoc, Nat.add_shuffle3.
  symmetry.
  rewrite Nat.add_comm, Nat.add_assoc, <- Nat.mul_add_distr_l.
  replace (S j) with (j + 1) by now rewrite Nat.add_comm.
  rewrite Nat.add_assoc. symmetry.
  now rewrite Nat.mul_add_distr_l, <- !Nat.add_assoc.
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the automatic tactics for arithmetic:

```
Require Import Coq.omega.Omega.

Lemma U i j : 3 * S (i + j) + 1 = S (3 * i + 1) + S (3 * j + 1).
now omega.
Qed.
```

Indeed some of these proofs are very time consuming, see the Coq manual for more details about the existing tactics. If you want to do the proof manually, I'd proceed as:

```
simpl; rewrite !add_0_r, !add_1_r, !add_succ_r, !add_assoc; simpl.
```

and add to my auxiliary library a few interchange lemmas.

Comment: That's very cool! I found that it's easy to finish your proof with `do 5 f_equal.`, and then add several rewrites ending with `; f_equal`, like this one: `rewrite <- !Nat.add_assoc; f_equal`.

Comment: I think the `f_equal` is not actually needed, however Coq's `rewrite` seems so poor at pattern selection that people do resort to that tricks. What I would use is another rewrite `add_AACCA` to close the proof, where the `add_AACCA` lemma is the proper interchange lemma. If Coq had a decent stdlib and a decent `rewrite` tactic the manual proof would indeed be one line, as it is in ssreflect.